# How to pass the height of parent widget to child widget in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to pass the height of stack from parent widget in Flutter
but i am unable to do it.kindly help me to find the solution,
I am putting my code for the reference.

**Parent widget**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        children: [

          Picturebackground(//pass Stack height ),

          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('varying text'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Children Widget**

```
dynamic listImagesnotFound = ['assets/svg1.svg','assets/svg2.svg','assets/svg3.svg','assets/svg4.svg'];
Random rnd;

class Picturebackground extends StatelessWidget {
  final double stack_height;
  Picturebackground ({Key key, this.stack_height}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = listImagesnotFound.length - 1;
    rnd = new Random();
    int r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
    String image_name = listImagesnotFound[r].toString();
    return SvgPicture.asset(image_name,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: // get the height of the Stack
    );
  }
}
```

How can i pass Height of Stack to SvgPicture.

Comment: I am wondering what is the use case of the above code?
- If you want to fit the image in the screen, use MediaQuery to get the height.

Comment: @Pushpendra : i've tryed the MediaQuery but i wasn't helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LayoutBuilder` to get the constraints of the `Picturebackground` widget:

```dart
dynamic listImagesnotFound = ['assets/svg1.svg','assets/svg2.svg','assets/svg3.svg','assets/svg4.svg'];
Random rnd;

class Picturebackground extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = listImagesnotFound.length - 1;
    rnd = new Random();
    int r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
    String image_name = listImagesnotFound[r].toString();

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        // get here
        final height = constraints.maxHeight;

        return SvgPicture.asset(image_name,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: height // use here
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: since SingleChildScrollView does not constrain the height of its child, you need to use a SizedBox outside of your Stack with some height, or you need to constrain it in some other way. Or even remove the SingleChildScrollView (in the example it does not seem to be used).